# Setting up Spring MVC using pom.xml, with slfj logging and leaks

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, slf4j

Below is what I have in my pom.xml, any comments or improvments? (this is for a spring mvc application)

Do I still need to exclude commons logging to use slf4j?

```
<!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've had this in a project like this for about 1 year now, and not sure if things have changed or need updating (especially around setting up the logging).

One thing I hate is when using IntelliJ and jetty (that reloads the project every x seconds), is that I get java out of memory (perm gen) errors and I believe it is because of a leak in the logging in the spring framework.

Comment: Can you please include he results of "mvn dependency:tree" as part of your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should exclude `commons-logging` only when you have `jcl-over-slf4j` included. See for more info: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e787
About leaks: as far I understand there is not proper fix -- you could increase memory, but it will crash later. This is one of problems which [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) may help to reduce.